# Download an HTML version of an XML page

Tags: html, xml, google-chrome

There's a web page which renders fine but when I try to save as, it gives me an XML instead of html page. 
How can I download an html version?

I used fetch but it's the same.

Thanks.

EDIT: I found the XSL file in the chrome dev tools network tab if that helps.

Comment: You need to find the XSL that renders the XML. That COULD be a browser extension

Comment: I found the XSL in the network tab of chrome dev tools but it doesn't contain data.

Comment: I put both the XSL and XML in the same folder and changed the href for the xsl in the xml to the same folder but no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Here are several options and tools that could assist you. Apart from straight `Save as...` there exist browser plugins to help you with that as well. Take a look at the following:

- https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/save-complete-webpage-offline-reading/
- https://lifehacker.com/how-to-save-web-pages-for-offline-access-later-5957617
- https://websitedownloader.io/

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to do it from the chrome console automatically with javascript so I'm not sure how to use the plugin in there